# How to modify cacti GUI to call a script independent of the protocols like SNMP or WMI?

Tags: user-interface, monitoring, nagios, zabbix, cacti

I want to fetch data to cacti gui(any monitoring tool GUI) from a database table which is at remote database(MYSQL) server without using any agent or protocol like SNMP or WMI, So please suggest me the way to implement this.I am totally a newbie in this kind of work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Zabbix, you can use ODBC queries to fetch data you wish to monitor. Please see [ODBC monitoring section](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks) in Zabbix documentation.

Comment: Thanks a ton, you made my day.Its last part of my academic project. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PHP script to get the data for you in Cacti.

http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/making_scripts_work_with_cacti.html

https://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-monitoring-plugins/